# Ошибка при установке Rainmeter

Tags: rainmeter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После удаления Rainmeter снова не получается её установить, такая ошибка вылезает, хотя я выбрал стандартную установку.
Может кто-нибудь знает в чем проблема?